# Custom react-native webview in objective-c

Tags: ios, react-native, webview

I want to create custom web-view component for ios react-native application.
I did everything according to the instructions, but got an error when launch application in emulator:

"...reactNativeComponent "SecuredWebView" was not found in UIManager..."

Here is official manual:
[Custom WebView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/custom-webview-ios)

[This is error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsJyP.png)

This is my project's files in ios folder:

**SecuredWebView.h**

```
#ifndef SecuredWebView_h
#define SecuredWebView_h

#import <React/RCTWebView.h>

@interface SecuredWebView : RCTWebView
@end

#endif /* SecuredWebView_h */
```

**SecuredWebView.m**

```
#import "SecuredWebView.h"

@interface SecuredWebView ()
@end

@implementation SecuredWebView { }
@end
```

**SecuredWebViewManager.h**

```
#ifndef SecuredWebViewManager_h
#define SecuredWebViewManager_h

#import <React/RCTWebViewManager.h>

@interface SecuredWebViewManager : RCTWebViewManager
@end

#endif /* SecuredWebViewManager_h */
```

**SecuredWebViewManager.m**

```
#import "SecuredWebViewManager.h"
#import "SecuredWebView.h"

@interface SecuredWebViewManager () <RCTWebViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation SecuredWebViewManager { }
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (UIView *)view
{
  SecuredWebView *webView = [SecuredWebView new];
  webView.delegate = self;
  return webView;
}
@end
```

Call in react-native module:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  NativeModules,
  requireNativeComponent,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const { SecuredWebViewManager } = NativeModules;

const Portal = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.body}>
      <WebView
        style={styles.root}
        source={{ uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/' }}
        nativeConfig={{
          component: SecuredWebViewComponent,
          viewManager: SecuredWebViewManager,
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  body: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
});

const SecuredWebViewComponent = requireNativeComponent(
  'SecuredWebView',
  Portal,
  WebView.extraNativeComponentConfig,
);

export default Portal;
```

I will be grateful for help, what's wrong in my code.

Comment: Resolved by myself! Changed functional Portal component to classic class Portal extends React.PureComponent. And error is gone!